# How do I connect bare metal worker to docker TSA host

Tags: concourse

I have followed the docker-compose concourse installation [set up](https://concourse.ci/docker-repository.html)

Everything is up and running but I cant figure out what to use as `--tsa-host` value in command to connect worker to TSA host

Would be worth mentioning that docker concourse web and db are running on the same machine that I hope to use as bare metal worker.

I have tried 1. to use IP address of concourse web container but no joy. I cannot even ping the docker container IP from host.

1.

```
sudo ./concourse worker   --work-dir ./worker   --tsa-host IP_OF_DOCKER_CONTAINER   --tsa-public-key host_key.pub  
--tsa-worker-private-key worker_key
```

I have also tried using the 2. CONCOURSE_EXTERNAL_URL and 3. the ip address of the host but no luck either.

2.

```
sudo ./concourse worker   --work-dir ./worker   --tsa-host http://10.XXX.XXX.XX:8080   --tsa-public-key host_key.pub  
--tsa-worker-private-key worker_key
```

3.

```
sudo ./concourse worker   --work-dir ./worker   --tsa-host 10.XXX.XXX.XX:8080   --tsa-public-key host_key.pub  
--tsa-worker-private-key worker_key
```

Other details of setup:

1. Mac OSX Sierra
2. Docker For Mac

Comment: I had this similar setup working with vagrant concourse lite but I need the latest concourse v3.4.0 to use the caching feature

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm you use the internal IP of the host, not public IP, not container IP.

```
--tsa-host <INTERNAL_IP_OF_HOST>
```

If you use `docker-compose.yml` as in its setup document, you needn't care of TSA-HOST, the environmen thas been defined already

```
  CONCOURSE_TSA_HOST: concourse-web
```

Comment: Tried without providing --tsa-host and got following error {"timestamp":"1503412223.665370464","source":"worker","message":"worker.beacon.restarting","log_level":2,"data":{"error":"failed to dial: failed to connect to TSA: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2222: getsockopt: connection refused","session":"4"}}

Comment: Also, I can confirm that I have tried using internal ip of host

Answer (score 0):

I used the docker-compose.yml recently with the steps described here https://concourse-ci.org/docker-repository.html .

Please confirm that there is a keys directory next to the docker-compose.yml after you executed the steps.

```
mkdir -p keys/web keys/worker

ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ./keys/web/tsa_host_key -N ''
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ./keys/web/session_signing_key -N ''

ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ./keys/worker/worker_key -N ''

cp ./keys/worker/worker_key.pub ./keys/web/authorized_worker_keys
cp ./keys/web/tsa_host_key.pub ./keys/worker

export CONCOURSE_EXTERNAL_URL=http://192.168.99.100:8080

docker-compose up
```